# Add two rewrite conditions to htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file on root.On root folder there are three files.

1. index.php
2. article.php
3. event.php

on index.php there two href to event and news.php files.

on article.php:

```
$articleId=123;
$articleTitle='First Article';
echo '<a href="'.$articleId.'&'.str_replace(" ","-",$articleTitle).'">Read More</a>';
```

and to event.php:

```
$eventId=789;
$eventTitle='First Event';
echo '<a href="'.$eventId.'&'.str_replace(" ","-",$eventTitle).'">Read More</a>';
```

Above two href's are on the index.php.

To handle the redirect i have written following code on htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) article.php?arid=$1&$2
RewriteRule (.*) event.php?eveid=$1&$2
```

But when i add the second rewrite line,system is not loading and when i remove one rewrite condition system works fine.
can anyone help me out?.

Thanks in advance and hope i have clearly mention the question.

Comment: What are the URLs you want to see in your browser for article and event?

Comment: @anubhavawhen article:localhost/system/articleid-articletitle and then for event : localhost/system/eventid-eventtitle

Comment: What is `/system/` folder here? Are you placing your php files inside it?

Comment: @anubhava:yes you are correct

Comment: But your PHP code is making href as `articleid&articletitle` or I misunderstood anything?

Comment: its actually directs to article.php and event.php.do i need to have the page name on href tag?.

Comment: If both event and article links look identical, how is mod_rewrite supposed to know which one is supposed to route to an article and which one to route to an event?

Comment: @JonLin:yes, but how can i write a if statement on htaccess files?.with the link we can pass the type saying event or news?.

Comment: there are no if statements for mod_rewrite

Comment: @JonLin:so how can i do this?.any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your server can't know if, for example, `12&my-article` is an article or is an event. So your server takes the first rule which matches the url.

So, I think you have to differentiate both kind of url, like `article-12&my-article` and `event-7&my-event`. Now, the .htaccess file will be :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule article-(.*) article.php?arid=$1&$2
RewriteRule event-(.*) event.php?eveid=$1&$2
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make link like this
     < a href="/art-123-articleTitle.html">Read More< /a >

and the Rule for it ('art' is for article.php)

```
RewriteRule ^art\-(\d+)\-(.*)\.html$ article.php?arid=$1&artitle=$2 [L]
```

and so on